# Is there any difference between these two ways of creating new functions (with pre-filled arguments) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to provide a set of functions, each based on the `apiCall` one (which has the logic for query params handling, URL formatting, etc.), but with pre-filled arguments.

So I used `bind` in `getProducts` and `getCategories` but also an anonymous function in `getProduct`, because I need the passed `id` value.

I'm wondering if there is any drawback, issue or even any difference between the two ways?

```
// ...
// apiVersion, storeId and accessToken are provided
const boundApiCall = apiCall.bind(null, apiVersion, storeId, accessToken);

return {
    apiVersion,
    storeId,
    accessToken,
    apiCall: boundApiCall,
    getProduct: id => boundApiCall.call(null, `products/${id}`),
    getProducts: boundApiCall.bind(null, 'products'),
    getCategories: boundApiCall.bind(null, 'categories'),
};
```

Comment: I assume you use this along the lines of `obj.getProduct(42)` and `obj.getCategories()`, correct?

Comment: Yes some sort of - thanks for asking